# How to idiomatically iterate over a mutable vector while examining other elements

Tags: rust

I want to write code like this:

```
let mut v: Vec<Object> = Vec::new();
for e in v.iter_mut() {
  if e.some_predicate() {
    e.val = v.iter().filter(|o| o.some_predicate()).count();
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because the for loop takes a mutable borrow, and then the `iter` tries to do an immutable borrow.  I understand why the borrow checker doesn't like the specific types produced, but the operation I'm trying to do seems safe, and if I rewrite it to use indices it works fine:

```
let mut v: Vec<Object> = Vec::new();
for i in 0..v.len() {
  if v[i].some_predicate() {
    v[i].val = v.iter().filter(|o| o.some_predicate()).count();
  }
}
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this in rust?

Comment: In this particular case, I'd say using indices _is_ the idiomatic way to write it.

Comment: The answer might well be what @user4815162342 has said. There _could_ be a "better" answer but it would depend on exactly what the predicates are.

Answer (score 0):

When approaching such problems, you have to think about whether you can separate *reads* from *writes*. Thus, we need to pick up the places where `e.val` changes will trigger the total `count` changes and split it. As it happens, only when `some_predicate()` switches from `true` to `false` we may [rewrite the code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=struct+Object+%7B+val%3A+usize+%7D%0A%0Aimpl+Object+%7B%0A++fn+some_predicate%28%26self%29+-%3E+bool+%7B%0A++++true+%2F%2F+depends+on+self.val%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn+test%28%29+%7B%0A++let+mut+v%3A+Vec%3CObject%3E+%3D+Vec%3A%3Anew%28%29%3B%0A++let+mut+count+%3D+v.iter%28%29.filter%28%7Co%7C+o.some_predicate%28%29%29.count%28%29%3B%0A%0A++for+e+in+%26mut+v+%7B%0A++++if+e.some_predicate%28%29+%7B%0A++++++e.val+%3D+count%3B%0A++++++if+%21e.some_predicate%28%29+%7B%0A++++++++count+-%3D+1%3B%0A++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A) as follows:

```rust
let mut v: Vec<Object> = Vec::new();
let mut count = v.iter().filter(|o| o.some_predicate()).count();

for e in &mut v {
  if e.some_predicate() {
    e.val = count;
    if !e.some_predicate() {
      count -= 1;
    }
  }
}
```

I can't say this solution *is* idiomatic because every problem is unique. But we've got several speed improvements. Now we don't have to compute the predicate N² times. As well as the vector's access also has become linear. We don't use indices, so there are no extra boundary checks.